# transforming data first vs doing everything in pipe results in different results when using a model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I wanted to make all of the custom transformations I make to my data in a pipe. I thought that I could use it as `pipe.fit_transform(X)` to transform my X before using it in a model, but I also thought that I'll be able to append to the pipeline model itself and simply use it as one using `pipe.steps.append(('model', self.model))`.

Unfortunately, after everything was built I've noticed that I'm getting different results when transforming the data and using it directly in a model vs doing everything in one pipeline. Have anyone experienced anything like this?

Adding code:

```
# Base pipeline to be used
BASE_PIPE = Pipeline([
                ('dim_increase_num', data_num_mix()),
                ('dim_increase_cat', data_cat_mix()),
                ('start', data_get_dummies()),
                ('dm_correlation', data_x_corr_()),
                ('scaler', DFStandardScaler()),
                ('column_ectraction', ColumnExtractor(columns_catboost)),
                ])

class base_model_class:
    def fit_predict(self, X_train:pd.DataFrame=X_train, y_train:pd.Series=y_train, X_test:pd.DataFrame=X_test):
        return self.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
    def evaluate(self, X:pd.DataFrame=X, y:pd.Series=y):
        X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.25,random_state=0)
        y_pred = self.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
        result= r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
        return result

class model_linear_regression(base_model_class):
    def __init__(self, pipe=None, inverse=False):
        self.name = 'Linear_Regression'
        self.model = LinearRegression()
        
        if pipe==None:
            self.pipe = Pipeline([('model', self.model)])
        else:
            self.pipe = deepcopy(pipe)
            self.pipe.steps.append(('model', self.model))

        if inverse:
            self.pipe = TransformedTargetRegressor( regressor=self.pipe,
                                                    func=np.log1p, 
                                                    inverse_func=np.expm1)
    def fit(self, X:pd.DataFrame=X_train, y:pd.Series=y_train):
        self.pipe.fit(X, y)
        return self
    def predict(self, X:pd.DataFrame=X_test):
        y_pred = self.pipe.predict(X)
        return y_pred
```

And then, when using everything gives different R2 scores:

```
Xx=BASE_PIPE.fit_transform(X)

model_linear_regression(inverse=False).evaluate(Xx,y)
>>> 0.7415005607713974

model_linear_regression(BASE_PIPE, inverse=False).evaluate(X,y)
>>> -6.306970505602111e+22
```

**EDIT:**
providing all steps in pipeline used:

```
class data_num_mix(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, columns:list=NUMERIC_FEATURES):
        self.columns = columns
    def fit(self, X, y = None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X, y = None):
        X_ = X.copy()
        self.frames = [X_]
        for col in self.columns:
            A = pd.DataFrame(X_[col].map(lambda x: np.sqrt(x) if x>0 else -np.sqrt(-x)))
            A = A.rename(columns={col:col+'^s'})
            self.frames += [A]

            B = pd.DataFrame(X_[col] * X_[col])
            B = B.rename(columns={col:col+'^2'})
            self.frames += [B]
        return pd.concat(self.frames, axis=1)


class data_cat_mix(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, columns:list=CATEGORICAL_FEATURES):
        self.columns = columns
    def fit(self, X, y = None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X, y = None) -> pd.DataFrame:
        X_ = X.copy()
        for col in self.columns:
            df_col_count = X_[col].value_counts().to_frame().reset_index()
            df_col_count.columns = ["var_name", "var_count"]
            df_col_count["var_freq"] = df_col_count["var_count"] / df_col_count["var_count"].sum()

            X_['C_'+col] = X_[col].replace(df_col_count.set_index('var_name')['var_count'])
            X_['F_'+col] = X_[col].replace(df_col_count.set_index('var_name')['var_freq'])
        return X_


class data_get_dummies(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, columns:list = CATEGORICAL_FEATURES):
        self.columns = columns
        self.encoder = make_column_transformer((OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore", sparse=False), self.columns),remainder='passthrough')
    def fit(self, X, y = None):
        self.encoder.fit(X)
        return self
    def transform(self, X, y = None) -> pd.DataFrame:
        X_ = X.copy()
        encoder_columns = self.encoder.get_feature_names_out()
        fixed_columns = [x.replace('onehotencoder__','').replace('remainder__','') for x in encoder_columns ]
        df_temp=pd.DataFrame(self.encoder.transform(X_), columns=fixed_columns)
        return df_temp


class data_x_corr(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, columns:list=NUMERIC_FEATURES_, corr_val:float=0.95):
        self.columns = columns
        self.corr_val = corr_val
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        # prepare numeric df
        X_ = X.copy()
        x = X_[self.columns]

        corr_matrix = x.corr(method='spearman')
        iters = range(len(corr_matrix.columns) - 1)
        drop_cols = []

        # Iterates through Correlation Matrix Table to find correlated columns
        for i in iters:
            for j in range(i):
                item = corr_matrix.iloc[j:(j+1), (i+1):(i+2)]
                col = item.columns
                row = item.index
                val = item.values
                if val >= self.corr_val:
                    drop_cols.append(i)

        drops = sorted(set(drop_cols))[::-1]
        # Drops the correlated columns
        for i in drops:
            col = x.iloc[:, (i+1):(i+2)].columns.values
            X_ = X_.drop(col, axis=1)
        return X_


class DFStandardScaler(TransformerMixin):
    # StandardScaler but for pandas DataFrames
    def __init__(self):
        self.ss = None
        self.mean_ = None
        self.scale_ = None
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.ss = StandardScaler()
        self.ss.fit(X)
        self.mean_ = pd.Series(self.ss.mean_, index=X.columns)
        self.scale_ = pd.Series(self.ss.scale_, index=X.columns)
        return self
    def transform(self, X) -> pd.DataFrame:
        # assumes X is a DataFrame
        Xss = self.ss.transform(X)
        Xscaled = pd.DataFrame(Xss, index=X.index, columns=X.columns)
        return Xscaled
    def __str__(self):
         return "DF_StandardScaler"
    def __repr__(self):
         return "DF_StandardScaler"


class ColumnExtractor(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, cols):
        self.cols = cols
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        # stateless transformer
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        # assumes X is a DataFrame
        Xcols = X[self.cols]
        return Xcols
```

Comment: Doing everything in one pipe ends up using the pipe's `fit_transform` method on the training dataset and only the `transform` method on the test set (to avoid leakage); would any of your steps have different behavior based on that?

Comment: @BenReiniger it makes sense what you wrote, about data leakage and yes I do have transformers that fits the data first i.e. StandardScaler rewritten in `pd.DataFrame` format. But can such drastic changes appear because of the scaler?

Comment: It is unlikely that a scaler leaking test data would cause a reversal of R2 score as drastic as you're seeing.  But if the scaler is additionally doing something _wrong_, or any of the other steps (that you haven't defined for us), that could very well cause this kind of issue.

Comment: @BenReiniger well... I've built all of my transformers without fit method (fit -> returns self). Do you have any tips for finding the issue?

Comment: Would be much better if you could provide a sample dataset so we could really run it.

Comment: @MohammadBadriAhmadi you are right, should have added it in the first place... yet i though that it would be easier to fix... For the dataset itself, I cannot add it, but it's a regression task for housing prices

Comment: I understand you cannot share your own dataset however you can add a simulated data set or use random variables, we just need an example of your dataset so we can reproduce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one transformer that stands out to me is `data_cat_mix`, specifically the count-of-level columns. When applied to train+test, these are consistent (but leaks test information); when applied separately, the values in train will generally be much higher (just from its size being three times larger), so the model doesn't really understand how to treat them in the test set.

Comment: hmm, you're right. Do you think it would be best to remove the count and be left with frequency? Or is there a technique that could help me out?

Comment: P.S. you were right, the issue was with this transformer: I removed the count transformation and now the code produce  EXACTLY the same results.

Comment: The right way to do this is to get the counts and frequencies at `fit` time, saving them to attributes, and then use them at `transform` time.  fwiw, I know that `category_encoders` and `feature_engine` both include count-encoders, and `pyvtreat` appears to include such columns in certain situations.